# How best to setup Room and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, android-room

I'm currently trying to setup Room with Retrofit. I have a working implementation...

It requests an `ApiItemBean`, then the `ApiDatabase` calls its `ApiItemDAO` to map a databased or new `ApiItem` with the `ApiItemBean` into a `Single<ApiItem>`.

That single is used in the `ApiRepository` by the `ApiRequest`, and eventually subscribed to in the figurative `Usage`.

**ApiItemBean**

```
  public class ApiItemBean {
    private final int a;
    private final int b;
    public ApiItemBean(int a, int b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    }
    public int a() {
      return a;
    }
    public int b() {
      return b;
    }
  }
```

**ApiItem**

```
  @Entity(tableName = "api_item") public static class ApiItem {
    @PrimaryKey private final int id;
    ApiItem(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
    public int id() {
      return id;
    }
  }
```

**ApiItemDAO**

```
  @Dao public interface ApiItemDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) long insert(ApiItem apiItem);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM api_item WHERE id = :id") ApiItem apiItem(int id);
  }
```

**ApiDatabase**

```
  @Database(entities = { ApiItem.class }, version = 1) abstract class ApiDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract ApiItemDAO apiItemDAO();
    // More...

    Single<ApiItem> mapApiItem(ApiItemBean apiItemBean) {
      final ApiItem apiItem = new ApiItem(apiItemBean.a());
      final ApiItem apiItemDb = apiItemDAO().apiItem(apiItem.id());
      if (apiItemDb == null || !apiItemDb.equals(apiItem))
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.format("insert=%s", apiItemDAO().insert(apiItem)));
      return Single.just(apiItemDAO().apiItem(apiItem.id()));
    }
    // More...
  }
```

**ApiRequest**

```
  public interface ApiRequest {
    @GET("API_ITEM_BEAN_REQUEST") Single<ApiItemBean> getApiItemBean();
    // More...
  }
```

**ApiRepository**

```
  public class ApiRepository {
    private final ApiRequest apiRequest;
    private final ApiDatabase apiDatabase;
    ApiRepository(ApiRequest apiRequest, ApiDatabase apiDatabase) {
      this.apiRequest = apiRequest;
      this.apiDatabase = apiDatabase;
    }
    Single<ApiItem> getApiItem() {
      return apiRequest.getApiItemBean().flatMap(apiDatabase::mapApiItem);
    }
    // More...
  }
```

**Usage**

```
  public class Usage {
    private final ApiRepository apiRepository;
    Usage(ApiRepository apiRepository) {
      this.apiRepository = apiRepository;
    }
    public void onUse() {
      apiRepository.getApiItem().subscribe();
    }
  }
```

I am unsure on how best to check the requests against the database. See `ApiDatabase::mapApiItem` for an example of how I thought to do it.

Side note: I know there is no specific question, and should possibly be moved to CodeReview, however the code example is not fully working considering it would need to depend on a specific api and I thought it best to try here first. Sorry to any mods.

Comment: Google provided a nice sample app which demonstrates exactly that: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample